# How to customize effect plot in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to some effects plots to visualize regression results.  I'm able to create the plot, but many of the arguments I'm supplying don't seem to affect its appearance.  For example, this code produces 3 figures of nearly identical appearance.  The multiline and rug settings don't seem to work.  Am I doing this correctly?  Is there an issue caused by the fact that these are considered "legacy arguments" in the documentation?  I'm using R 3.5.1 in RStudio.  Many thanks!

```
data("iris")
m = lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species + Species*Petal.Width, data=iris)
print(plot(effect("Petal.Width*Species", m, x.var="Petal.Width", z.var="Species", multiline=TRUE, rug=FALSE)))
print(plot(effect("Petal.Width*Species", m, x.var="Petal.Width", z.var="Species", multiline=FALSE, rug=FALSE)))
print(plot(effect("Petal.Width*Species", m, x.var="Petal.Width", z.var="Species", multiline=FALSE, rug=TRUE)))
```

#

Comment: What package are you using for the `effect()` function? Where are the `multiline=` and `rug=` parameters documented?

Comment: The `multiline=` and `rug=` arguments are for `effects:::plot.eff`, not for `effects::effect`. (On more reading, so are `x.var` and `z.var`.)

Comment: It's from the effects package. I believe this is the relevant documentation:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/effects/versions/4.0-2/topics/summary.eff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly putting the arguments for `plot` within `effects`. This works:

```
m = lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species + Species*Petal.Width, data=iris)
plot(effect("Petal.Width*Species", m), x.var="Petal.Width", z.var="Species", multiline=TRUE, rug=FALSE)
plot(effect("Petal.Width*Species", m), x.var="Petal.Width", z.var="Species", multiline=FALSE, rug=FALSE)
plot(effect("Petal.Width*Species", m), x.var="Petal.Width", z.var="Species", multiline=FALSE, rug=TRUE)
```

(Notice the paren after `m`, closing off the argument list for `effect`.)

Comment: Thank you so much!  This answers my question.